# Windows Iot webcam preview image error

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, webcam, windows-10-iot-core

I am using a webcam on my raspberry pi model 3 running windows iot. once i initialize the camera and the preview begins every couple seconds the preview flashes random colors.

I am not sure if it has to do the initialization settings. the camera i am using is: ELP-USBFHD04H
[Camera Specs](https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/2MP-1920-x-1080-wide-view-2-1mm-lens-mini-38x38mm-camera-module-H-264-MJPEG/1762679_32425673342.html)

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Post some of your source code so others can help.

Comment: Have you tested with [this sample](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/webcamapp)?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Yes I have tested with that sample project and the problem remains. the camera loads and the preview begins, capturing a photo works as well but the preview continues to flash various colors.

Comment: Can you capture a snapshot of "flash various colors" and show it here?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I recorded a couple seconds of my screen and made a gif. Here is the link: https://gifyu.com/image/zkyC

Comment: There is a related known issue that Windows 10 IoT Core support for camera peripheral devices with Raspberry Pi devices is limited. You can reference [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/releasenotesrtm).

Comment: I understand that fine tuning and optimization of the camera settings are a necessity. I was looking to see if anyone had any information on how to initialize settings in which would prevent these graphical interruptions from occurring